# Installing private pip package inside docker container

Tags: python, docker, github, pip

I am trying to create docker container for a fastapi application.
This application is going to use a private pip package hosted on github.

During local development, I used the following command to install the dependency:

```bash
pip install git+https://<ACCESS_TOKEN>:x-oauth-basic@github.com/username/projectname
```

I tried the same approach inside dockerfile, however without success

```
FROM python:3.9

WORKDIR /code

COPY ./requirements.txt /code/requirements.txt

ARG ACCESS_TOKEN=default_value

RUN /usr/local/bin/python -m pip install --upgrade pip
RUN echo "pip install git+https://${ACCESS_TOKEN}:x-oauth-basic@github.com/username/projectname"
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir --upgrade -r requirements.txt

COPY . /code

CMD ["uvicorn", "app:app", "--host", "0.0.0.0", "--port", "8080"]
```

```bash
docker build --build-arg ACCESS_TOKEN=access_token_value .
```

The container builds without errors and during the build process I can see that the token is passed correctly.
However, after running the container with `docker run <containerid>` I get the following error:

```bash
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'projectname'
```

Have anyone tried such thing before?
Is it the correct approach?

Comment: Hi :) Why don't you try `RUN eval "pip ...."` instead of `echo`? I see no useful case of using `echo` in the middle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if I am not mistaken, you could run your pip command without `echo`:

```
RUN pip install git+https://${ACCESS_TOKEN}:x-oauth-basic@github.com/username/projectname
```